# How to do the Loomis method of drawing the head at an angle that isn't 3/4?

Tags: drawing

Everyone who teaches the Loomis  method of drawing the head from an angle always shows the 3/4 angle.  For example, see the middle picture below.  Apparently, at this angle the eclipse on the side of the head just contacts the border of the sphere of the Loomis head construction, which is convenient. But what happens when the head turns a little farther to the right and the border of the eclipse passes the border of the sphere.  Also, as the turns to the right, when does the eclipse on the left side appear, and how does it first appear?   I can't find any description of this.[image]

Comment: Isnt your front construction wrong? The part of the are of the ellipse is flat but in your front view it isnt. This would go a long way to solving your problem. Dunno would have to consult my loomis book.

Comment: don't over-think it: this is a shorthand construction that, when you actually look at a skull has very little bearing on reality. It is a *useful scaffold*. Your question would be better answered via study of anatomy.

Comment: @joojaa   Those aren't my drawings.  I picked them up off the internet.  There are hundreds more just like them.  But you can't any drawings at angles in between these three.